# Ionic App is crashing after login, when I run build on Android emulator

Tags: angular, android-studio, ionic-framework, android-emulator, capacitor

**Note** : *its and ionic (Capacitor) project and i am using Android Studio for testing.*

```
   requestNotificationsPermissions(): void {
        PushNotifications.requestPermission().then(result => {
            if (result.granted) {
                PushNotifications.register();
            }
        }).catch((err: any) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Any particular error ouput on the console?

Comment: There is no error output....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are using `PushNotifications`.

It used to happen to me when I forgot to include `google-services.json` in my Android project folder. If that is the case, include `google-services.json` inside `android/app/` folder.

See the official plugin docs: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/push-notifications#android